# Importing json data into MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, json, data-structures

Pretty much what the title says :)

At the moment I'm using Python to turn the json data into a plain-text tab-separated file, and then mysqlimport to pull that into my MySQL tables. Anyone know a nicer / more direct way?

Answer (score 0):

check this from Ayende.. might be some help..

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/03/05/actual-scenario-testing-with-raven.aspx

http://ayende.com/Blog/category/564.aspx

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/03/23/first-look-at-raven-db.aspx